# How to I automatically mount a ZFS pool on an external drive automatically on boot

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I recently moved an external/USB 3.0 hard drive on an ubuntu 19.04 desktop system from ext4 to ZFS. Previously, the drive would mount automatically to /media/user/drive_label on boot. If memory serves this was automatically done by gnome.

I've set up the reformatted drive to the same mount point, creating the drive with `sudo zpool create -m /media/user/drive_label storage /dev/sdb`.

It works fine *until* I reboot it. Once rebooted, I need to manually import the fs with `sudo zpool import storage` . Everything - permissions and such works fine, but I would like it imported without manual intervention.

On other filesystems - I'd add the drive to fstab, but it looks like zfs mounts things differently.

How do I get ubuntu to mount/import the drive automatically no boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [the instructions in the Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS#Using_zfs-mount-generator). Since I had ZFS as root on this I actually could skip some of the steps - ZED is already set up on my system.

zed will populate and automount the pool for me if there's a suitable configuration file. I created an empty file

`touch /etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache/storage`

ZED didn't pick it up and populate it so I gave it a kick by disabling and enabling a pool
`sudo zfs set canmount=off storage`
`sudo zfs set canmount=on storage`

I rebooted the system and checked to see if its mounted and it was.

Answer (score 1):

If the drive is connected at boot time, look at the `zfs-import-scan` service. That should scan all attached disks when it runs and import and mount the pools it finds.

Comment: Amazing. I've been scratching my head about this for a long time. Thanks.